# cfnUpdate WaiterUnrecoverableException

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy a cloudformation template via jenkins using cfnUpdate Plugin. This is my cfnUpdate code:

```
cfnUpdate(stack: ENV_LOWERCASE + "-ecs-windows",
                            file:'Deploy_DR/WindowsECSCluster.json', 
                            timeoutInMinutes:60,  
                            pollInterval:30000)
```

`WindowsECSCluster.json` is my cloudformation template.

But jenkins tends to throw this error:

[image]

My Cloudformation template works when i execute it outside of jenkins. It has default value entered for all parameters. Please do add any possible solutions for it.

**UPDATE**

So i removed the `pollInterval` from `cfnUpdate` and now it seems to show the original error:

```
| 2020-08-27 18:34:06.957   | dr-ecs-windows       | DELETE_IN_PROGRESS                   | Parameter validation failed: parameter value default for parameter name AutoScalingGroupSecurityGroups does not exist. Delete requested by u |
```

The parameter `AutoScalingGroupSecurityGroups` of the cloudformation template is a list of security groups. Right now the values are like:

`"sg-1,sg-2"`

which is of type `"List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>"`

I dont know why jenkins doesnt accept it even though cloudformation is executed correctly when run manually.

Comment: Try removing half of the resources in your CF template and run it again.  Keep doing that--either removing or adding things back--to see if you can isolate whether it is something in the template. You may also want to try loading your template to S3 and referencing it as an URL in your CF template.

Comment: Yes i did, to the point where its only creating a single resource. But i'm still getting the same error. Is the parameter 'params' of cfnUpdate compulsory?

Comment: No, https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/#cfnupdate-create-or-update-cloudformation-stack shows it as optional

Comment: @Shawn okay thanks..i have deployed jenkins in an ec2 instance within a private subnet...do u think that configuration has something to do with the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got the solution..thanks for the support btw

My polling interval was way too high. So i wasnt able to view the error in cloudformation within jenkins. I just removed it and then the error showed up.

I wrote a brief answer because it wasnt a very relevant question and i thought i should share it.

I specified the region using `withAws` and then executed `cfnUpdate`

```
withAWS(region: 'us-west-2')
                    {
                        cfnUpdate(stack: ENV_LOWERCASE + "-ecs-windows", 
                                file:'Deploy_DR/WindowsECSCluster.json', 
                                timeoutInMinutes:60)
                    }
```

It seems like the cloudformation was getting executed elsewhere...maybe `us-east-1`
and a parameter for security groups i provided wasnt working because that security group was not present in `us-east-1`